# sumarize (dplyr) con condicional según la existencia de una variable

Tags: r

Tengo un data.frame del que tengo que obtener un resumen, este data.frame no siempre va a contener las mismas variables, aunque sí conocemos las que pueden ser, por lo tanto no sé a priori las variables que tengo que totalizar (sumar), intento hacer un script reutilizable, en lugar de comprobar el data.frame y ver que variables contiene para después agrupar los datos, la idea es hacerlo de manera que con independencia de las que se hayan incorporado esté automatizada la agrupación:

```
newdf <- df %>%
group_by(colA) %>% 
summarize(colB = sum(colB),
          if(colC %in% colnames(df)){colC = sum(colC)},
          if(colD %in% colnames(df)){colD = sum(colD)},
          if(colE %in% colnames(df)){colE = sum(colE)}
          )
```

Pero esa estructura no es válida.

Gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo que la forma más simple y más natural a `dplyr` es la suma condicionada de [`summarise_at()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) que sería algo así:

```
library(tidyverse)

columnas_posibles <-  c("mpg", "disp", "otra")
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(matches(columnas_posibles)), sum)
```

`columnas_posibles` es un vector que inicializas previamente con los nombres de columnas de interés, tanto de un `data.frame` como de otro, en `mtcars` por ejemplo, no existe la columna `otra` sin embargo `sumarise_at` entiende que solo debe sumar aquellas columnas que coincidan con el vector de posibles.

El uso de `matches()` es útil, por que permite usar expresiones regulares para identificar nombres de columna, sin embargo, si se quiere coincidencias exactas, lo ideal es `any_of()`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(any_of(columnas_posibles)), sum)
```

Comment: Gracias Patricio, el inconveniente es que a priori no conozco las variables que va a incluir el data.frame (df), sé todas las que puede incluir, pero no siempre incluye las mismas. Además df incluye otras variables que no voy a resumir.

Comment: Tal vez te interpreté mal, entiendo que aunque no conozcas que variables  puede tener un data.frame SI sabes cual es el nombre de las que  quieres sumarizar, estén o no estén, es decir tus colB, colC, colD y colE ya las sabes de antemano. Si alguna de estás aparecierán en el data.frame,  entonces se sumarían. Esta es la idea de mi respuesta.

Comment: Patricio,  totalmente acertado, sencillamente perfecto. 
Lo que he observado es que ```matches()``` encuentra coincidencias cuando alguno de los elementos de ```columnas_posibles``` forma parte del texto de las columnas del data.frame. Es decir, no delimita las columnas a sólo las coincidencias exactas. Por tanto, si hay en el data.frame una columna 'otra col' también la tiene en cuenta para resumir.

Comment: Eso es cierto, por que `matches()` considera `columnas_posibles` como patrón regular, para hacer una búsqueda exacta, podrías hacer algo así: `columnas_posibles <-  c("^mpg$", "^disp$", "^otra$")`

Comment: Pero en realidad, me estaba olvidando de una forma incluso más simple mediante `any_of()`

Comment: Solución perfecta, gracias.

Comment: ¿sería posible adaptar la agrupación planteada para utilizarla con aggregate: ```aggregate(df[c("colB", "colC", "colD", "colE")], df[c("colA")], sum)```, es decir, hay alguna alternativa al uso de ```vars``` y ```any_of``` con aggregate?

Comment: Con `aggregate()` es un poco más complejo, tendrías que verificar previamente que columnas son las que tienes y cuales deberías sumarizar y crear dinámicamente   un formula de garupación.